# VSCode intellisense not working for angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

My angular 5 project is structured differently from the way CLI sets it up which is causing VSCode to think that its not an angular project which then breaks its intellisense in certain areas most notably in the HTML files where I cannot command+click methods to go to the respective TS file. any way to fool VSCode into thinking its an angular project?